# Determining if one array is contained in another

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I determine if one array is contained (element by element and in order) in another array?  I have written the program below in MSVS 2010 but not too sure how to complete the boolean function that determines if one array appears in the other one

```
void isContained( int ar1[], int ar2[] );


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ifstream fin1( "one.txt" );
    ifstream fin2( "two.txt" );

    int i, j, value1, value2;
    int arr1[ 10 ];
    int arr2[ 10 ];

    for ( i = 0 ; fin1 >> value1 ; i++ )
    {
        arr1[ i ] = value1;
    }

    for ( j = 0 ; fin2 >> value2 ; j++ )
    {
        arr2[ j ] = value2;
    }

    isContained( arr1, arr2 );

    system( "PAUSE" );
}


void isContained( int ar1[], int ar2[] )
{
    ???
}
```

Comment: You can use the `std::search` function from `<algorithm>`. There are a lot of useful functions in the standard library. You might want to familiarize yourself with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Let's say you want to check if `ar2` is contained in `ar1`.

An example:

```
Ar1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 2 8 2 4 2 4 6 2 9 1
Ar2: 2 4 6 2
```

Let's also assume you have the lengths of the arrays in `Ar1_len` and `Ar2_len`

You have to go through `Ar1`, find an element that matches the first element of `Ar2` then from there on, try to see if all elements match. If not, you continue on `Ar1` to find another element that matches the first element of `Ar2`

So basically the code would look something like this:

```
if (Ar2_len == 0)
    return true;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Ar1_len-(Ar2_len-1); ++i)
    if (Ar1[i] == Ar2[0])
    {
        bool matches = true;
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < Ar2_len; ++j)
            if (Ar1[i+j] != Ar2[j])
            {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        if (matches)
            return true;
    }
```

Note that `i` goes to `Ar1_len-(Ar2_len-1)` because if you are too far in the end of `Ar1` (where there are less than `Ar2_len` elements are left), it's obviously impossible to find `Ar2`.

Second note is that this is not the most efficient method. The most efficient method involves building a DFA from `Ar2` and using `Ar1` as its input and trace it. If it reaches final state you `return true`. This is probably a bit complicated for you know, but if you are interested, you could look up algorithms in string matching.

Final note is that, the code provided here is not meant for copy-paste. It may lack sufficient error checking and is solely here to give you the idea.

Comment: Note that the condition `Ar1[i]==Ar2[0]` is the `j==0` case of the looped-over condition `Ar1[i+j]==Ar2[j]`, and can be easily merged into it.  (DRY/SPOT principle, you know?)

Comment: ... and that the loop and it's equality check is equivalent to `std::mismatch`.

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is essentially a string searching algorithm (except that in your case your "characters" are the integer elements of your arrays).

There exists a variety of such algorithms, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

As far as your code so far is concerned:

1. You might want to make sure you don't go past the end of the arrays in your two `for` loops.
2. You need to pass the sizes of the two arrays to `isContained` (and its return type probably shouldn't be `void`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the prototype you gave the function.

Arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions, therefore there is no way the function could determine how many elements are in the arrays.

Comment: It is if the arrays are terminated by a special value (0 ?)

Comment: @Simon Which is kind of impossible when you are reading the data from user.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position in the containing array that would make [`mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) return the end of the contained array:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename OutIt, typename SeqIt>
OutIt find_sequence( OutIt outer_begin   , OutIt outer_end, 
                     SeqIt sequence_begin, SeqIt sequence_end ){
   assert( 
        distance(outer_begin,outer_end) >= distance(sequence_begin,sequence_end);

   // limit the possible iterator positions:
   OutIt outer_limit = outer_begin;
   advance( outer_limit, distance(sequence_begin, sequence_end) );

   for( OutIt outer_it = outer_begin; outer_it != outer_limit; ++outer_it ) 
   {
     if( mismatch( sequence_begin, sequence_end, outer_it ).first==sequence_end) 
     {
          return outer_it;
     }
   }
   // none found...
   return outer_end;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 int values[]  = { 1,2,3,4,5, 6 };

 int pattern[] = { 3,4,5 };

 int* pFound = find_sequence( values, end(values), pattern, end(pattern) );
 bool bFound = pFound != std::end(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::search` template in `<algorithm>` to search for a sub-sequence within another sequence. Note: I modified your function signature to pass the array sizes.

```
bool isContained(int ar1[], int size1, int ar2[], int size2)
{
    return std::search(ar1, ar1 + size1, ar2, ar2 + size2) != (ar1 + size1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is same as searching a substring in a string. There we are comparing characters, here we will compare numbers or array elements.

KMP[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTJr8OvyEVQ) algorithm is sought for such questions.

Comment: why the downvote? can the person tell why am I wrong?