# C++ Two n sized integer lists

Tags: c++, list, integer, compare

I'm new to C++ and I need some help creating this program:
I need to ask for the size of the list, then take the list containing integers and then ask the size of the second list and take those integers.

So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
long int ARR[10];
int i,n;

printf("List 1 size: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("List 1 data: ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%ld",&ARR[i]);

}
```

So that will take the input for the first list. Now I will repeat this for the second list. 
But the key point is I now need to compare the two lists. If list1 is in list2 then I say yay, or if not then nay.

How do I go about comparing these two lists? And I am I on the right track with the input?

Thanks,

EmptyPeace

Comment: Bad things happen if the user inputs a number greater than 10 for the list size.

Comment: Try using an `std::vector` instead.

Comment: can i leave it as long int ARR[];? or do i have to specify a length?

Comment: If you want to use an array then you have to specify a size. One of the advantages of `vector` is that it lets you specify the size at runtime, and even change the size after the vector has been created.

Comment: @Nick I have really very little knowledge in C++, how would i go about using std:vector?

Comment: @SteveJessop should i leave the size as something crazy like 99?

Comment: @Emptypeace: you can use 99, just as long as you check that the number the user entered is no more than 99. Or you could skip ahead to `vector` in whatever book or tutorial it is you're using to learn C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop would you mind elaborating? How would i go about taking the input for these two lists?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483634/determining-if-one-array-is-contained-in-another

Comment: <p>If you want to became a C++ programmer prefer STL. Buy a good book on C++.</p>
<p>Thinking in C++ is a very good and free book to learn c++: from beginning to intermediate</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

bool mypredicate (int i, int j) {
  return (i==j);
}

int main(){
    int size_list = 0;
    vector<int> list1, list2;

    cin >> size_list;

    list1.resize(size_list);
    list2.resize(size_list);

    cout << list1.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size_list; i++)
        cin >> list1[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_list; i++)
        cin >> list2[i];

    pair<vector<int>::iterator,vector<int>::iterator> mypair;
    mypair = mismatch (list1.begin(), list1.end(), list2.begin(), mypredicate);


    if( mypair.first == list1.end() && mypair.second == list2.end() )
        cout << "are equals" << endl;
    else{
        cout << "aren't " << endl;
        cout << *mypair.first << ", " << *mypair.second << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that is almost what I was looking for. The only thing is that list 2 can be a different size. I will create a new variable and ask for its size.

Comment: Then, take care using mismatch because if the second list is shorter than first can become an error.

Comment: Yes then I need to output aren't in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use either dynamic array or stl's vector to store data.

for example, dyn. array:

```
int size;
scanf("%d", size);
int *tab = new int[size];
...
delete[] tab;
```

or vector way:

```
#include <vector>
...
int size;
scanf("%d", size);
vector <int> tab(size);
// to insert an element, use tab.push_back( number );
// and getting an element goes array-way, for example tab[0];
```

And some words from me- if you are writing in c++, use cin and cout for input/output, unless you need extra speed or specific format. And remember, that [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type) is something different than array/vector.